# How do I get the thumbnail to display from a ACF Options page image with Timber/Twig

Tags: wordpress, twig, custom-wordpress-pages, timber, acfpro

I am developing a custom WordPress theme and having a difficult time getting the thumbnail image to display on my page from an ACF (Advanced Custom Fields) Options Page field, I am using timber/twig inside WordPress and have tried numerous ways with no success:

`{{options.tool_agreement.url }}` and `{{options.tool_agreement('thumbnail') }}` and `{{options.tool_agreement.thumbnail }}` and also `{{options.tool_agreement('thumbnail').url }}` and none of these are working for me??

~ Thanks for any tips!

Here is an example of the dump: `{{dump(options.tool_agreement)}}`

```
array (size=24)
  'ID' => int 254
  'id' => int 254
  'title' => string 'sample-agreement' (length=16)
  'filename' => string 'sample-agreement.jpg' (length=20)
  'filesize' => int 54741
  'url' => string 'https://protoolsite.local/wp-content/uploads/2021/07/sample-agreement.jpg' (length=78)
  'link' => string 'https://protoolsite.local/sample-agreement/' (length=48)
  'alt' => string '' (length=0)
  'author' => string '1' (length=1)
  'description' => string '' (length=0)
  'caption' => string '' (length=0)
  'name' => string 'sample-agreement' (length=16)
  'status' => string 'inherit' (length=7)
  'uploaded_to' => int 0
  'date' => string '2021-07-02 00:27:42' (length=19)
  'modified' => string '2021-07-02 00:27:42' (length=19)
  'menu_order' => int 0
  'mime_type' => string 'image/jpeg' (length=10)
  'type' => string 'image' (length=5)
  'subtype' => string 'jpeg' (length=4)
  'icon' => string 'https://protoolsite.local/wp-includes/images/media/default.png' (length=67)
  'width' => int 544
  'height' => int 703
  'sizes' => 
    array (size=18)
      'thumbnail' => string 'https://protoolsite.local/wp-content/uploads/2021/07/sample-agreement-150x150.jpg' (length=86)
      'thumbnail-width' => int 150
      'thumbnail-height' => int 150
      'medium' => string 'https://protoolsite.local/wp-content/uploads/2021/07/sample-agreement-232x300.jpg' (length=86)
      'medium-width' => int 232
      'medium-height' => int 300
      'medium_large' => string 'https://protoolsite.local/wp-content/uploads/2021/07/sample-agreement.jpg' (length=78)
      'medium_large-width' => int 544
      'medium_large-height' => int 703
      'large' => string 'https://protoolsite.local/wp-content/uploads/2021/07/sample-agreement.jpg' (length=78)
      'large-width' => int 544
      'large-height' => int 703
      '1536x1536' => string 'https://protoolsite.local/wp-content/uploads/2021/07/sample-agreement.jpg' (length=78)
      '1536x1536-width' => int 544
      '1536x1536-height' => int 703
      '2048x2048' => string 'https://protoolsite.local/wp-content/uploads/2021/07/sample-agreement.jpg' (length=78)
      '2048x2048-width' => int 544
      '2048x2048-height' => int 703
```

Comment: Choose one from `options.tool_agreement.sizes`

Comment: @DarkBee I think I have tried about every possible syntax, do you mean like this:  `{{options.tool_agreement.thumbnail}}` or `{{options.tool_agreement('thumbnail')}}` both of these don't return anything neither does this: `{{ Image(options.tool_agreement('thumbnail')) }}` or this `{{ Image(options.tool_agreement).thumbnail }}` I am at a loss?

Comment: `{{ options.tool_agreement.sizes.thumbnail }}` will provide the following output, `https://protoolsite.local/wp-content/uploads/2021/07/sample-agreement-150x150.jpg`

Comment: @DarkBee Sorry I did not read your first question properly, everything work now, accessing the "sizes" was a new thing for me a noob - Thanks again!